# Django print in prod' server

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I've gotten use to using print in my python code to show contents of variable and checking the shell output.
But i have now migrated all my work onto a online server. Pythonanywhere

I don't have the foggiest idea how to do the same now?
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Print to web console? To a file? Or even to the shell session?

Thanks

Comment: print statement will output to the web server out log, on pythonanywhere access to web tag, there are three logs there Access log:username.pythonanywhere.com.access.log
Error log:username.pythonanywhere.com.error.log
Server log:username.pythonanywhere.com.server.log

Comment: @Serjik please write a real answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On production server your print statements will output log to your webserver log files
In case of pythonanywhere there are three log files

> Access log:yourusername.pythonanywhere.com.access.log
>   Error log:yourusername.pythonanywhere.com.error.log
>   Server log:yourusername.pythonanywhere.com.server.log

those logs are accessible in your web tab page.

The logs you are looking for will be in server.log

Comment: also if you print to sys.stderr then it will show up in the error log (which may be less cluttered vs printing to stdout to the server log)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [Serjik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560572/296460) you can see the output of the console via the server log link on PythonAnywhere.

However the much better way to approach this is to use the Python [logging module.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). Using this module will solve many of these problems for you and solve many issues you may not have thought about (like thread safety). This lets you do things like filter log messages by severity and a whole bunch of other things.

To get started with that I would recommend having a look at the [basic logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial).

Comment: OP should be aware that the pythonanywhere server log may skip some prints due to size constraints. @shuttle87 's recommendation of logging module is more than welcome.

Comment: For pythonanywhere serve log limitations see: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12966/